# Usando variaveis de outras forms (C#)

Tags: c#, .net

Estou aprendendo programação com C#,usando o visual studio 2013.
Nesse programa tenho 2 janelas.
Na primeira janela tenho uma caixa de texto e um botão que grava o texto numa string e abre a segunda janela.
Na segunda janela tenho apenas uma caixa de texto .

Como eu faço para escrever na caixa de texto da janela 2 o que esta dentro a string da janela 1 ?
Obs.: Tentei tornar a string public mas não consigo acessar a string do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Poste o seu código, assim vamos poder te ajudar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma forma possível é declarar um construtor, na classe da segunda janela, que receba uma *string*:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    private string texto;

    public Form2(string texto)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.texto = texto;

        //utilize a variável texto para "setar" a sua caixa de texto
        textBox1.Text = texto;
    }
    .....
    .....
}
```

Para abrir a segunda janela use esse construtor:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Form2 form2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    form2.Show();    
}
```